British color animated movie portraying a small village reminiscent of early Disney films, with an old man transcending reality through music
I remember watching this on a VHS tape in early 2010, and I believe the movie to be much older. Unfortunately, I cannot give an exact decade range.
It is a British animated movie portraying the lives of villagers of a small British village. The movie was color animation, and overall the characters were in drawn style rather than CGI.
I remember the characters looking like early Disney movies such as Pinocchio (1940) and Alice in Wonderland (1951), where people look more "round" than "sharp." In a sense, the style is similar to Wyrd Sisters.
One scene I remember is of an old man who lives with his annoying wife, and he plays an instrument that looks like a piano or an organ. As he plays it, he transcends reality to reach the realm of music.
Also, I think there was a scene where a female character shows her bosom so it wasn't for general audiences.
I'm not sure whether there was narration or not, but the characters do speak. It was contemporary but kind of oldish, like 20th century. Also, there was a taste of fantasy, but it's not like there was actual "magic" in the story.
I've ruled out:

The Village (1993): The characters in the movie I'm looking for are more realistic than this, with noses, ears, and mouths depicted.

When the Wind Blows (1986): The movie I'm looking for isn't a disaster film.



I've swapped out the Wikipedia link for a YouTube vid since the wiki link didn't actually have any pictures!

Is there dialog in the movie or just a narration?

What genre? Sci-fi; medieval; contemporary etc.

Thank you for the modification. I'm not sure whether there was narration or not but the characters do speak. It was contemporary but kind of oldish like 20th century. Also there was a taste of fantasy but it's not like there was actual "magic" in the story

Could this be The Village (1993)?

The Village, a Vila or a Village is an Oscar-nominated short film by
Mark Baker released in 1993 in the United Kingdom. The short film was
animated with traditional hand drawn animation. The film was directed
and written by Baker, produced by Pam Dennis and other actors and crew
members, the animation tells the story of an isolated circular village
located in the middle of a large forest in Northern Britain. The
Church rules over the village as a figure of authority. The people in
the village are devout Christians following the church and obeying the
village priest, the villagers who are presented as hypocritical
"Sinners" most of the time spy on each other by looking out their
windows and peeping into one another's houses.





And there is indeed a bosom.

Thank you for letting me know of this movie but I'm afraid this isn't what I'm looking for. The characters of the movie I'm looking for are more realistic than this with nose and ears and mouth depicted
